# Dolly Zoom breaks orthographic view (Blender 2.8)

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a way to dolly zoom in an orthographic view without it switching to a 3D perspective view? I much prefer to work with a dolly zoom over a mouse wheel incremental zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the view3d.zoom tool instead of the view3d.dolly tool. As far as I can tell, they work the same, but the view3d.zoom doesn't break an orthographic view. Problem solved!